# Why does Try / Catch in Google Apps Script stop code execution in debug mode?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, try-catch, google-apps-script-editor

I am using Google Apps Script in a Google Sheet. I added some code recently that was causing an error due to me trying to access locked data. I tried some basic error trapping using Try / Catch and this works fine when I run my code, but in debug mode the program halts execution on the line in question. Am I using Try / Catch wrong, or is there something else I'm missing?

Here's my code:

```
  for (var i=0;i<userGroups.length;i++) {
    try {
      var temp = userGroups[i].getUsers();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error); 
    }
    ...
```

NOTE: I am NOT using the V8 runtime as it was causing me a lot of issues.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] including what runtime time are you using (old or Chrome V8).

Comment: Did you implement a breakpoint? The debugger is meant to stop at [breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints).

Comment: I've done a number of experiments tonight and the ONLY time I am able to replicate the problem in my post is when I get the error: You do not have permission to view the member list for the group: company-report@XXX.net (line 265, file "Code")

I can use Try / Catch to trap this error and that works fine when I run my code normally. But when I use debug mode my code breaks on getUsers() (the line in question).

Comment: (I tried to edit my post above, but I waited too long.) To be clear, I don't see this issue with any other errors I tried. It only seems to happen with permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you are not using V8, it is an intended behavior that the debugger stops execution at any error - handled or not

- Indeed, some users even [complain](https://issuetracker.google.com/152948662) about the fact that in V8 this feature has not been maintained.
- If you on the flipside are happy with the debugger not stopping execution at handled errors - change to V8.

Comment: I was just coming back to post this. An engineer at work wasn't able to reproduce my problem using v8. When he went back to the old version he saw what I was seeing.

I'll give v8 another try.

Comment: The debugger is pausing on V8 and I would really like to turn it off. :(

Comment: It's a stupid feature honestly. It ignores my breakpoint and rather goes on its own journey through a loop. No one can possibly sit through a loop iterating 100's of times and pressing continue each time.

Answer (score 1):

To work around the issue of the V8 debugger pausing on an error in a try catch, put the code with the try/catch in a library and call that code from your script by referencing the library. This way the try catch is occurring outside the debugger's control.